# Mysql: which fields matched using "OR"

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js

I have this query:

```
SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE username = "aaa" OR email = "abc@example.com" OR mobile = "123456789"
```

I can find which field did match like this:

```
var username = req.body.username;
var email = req.body.email;
var mobile = req.body.mobile;

database.query("SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE username = ? OR email = ? OR mobile = ?",[username, email, mobile, (err, result)=>{ 
        if (result.username == username) {...}
        if (result.email == email) {...}
        if (result.mobile == mobile) {...}
    }
```

But, I'd like to know which field did match without using `if` multiple times (if possible). So, is that possible form within Mysql only?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put it in the `SELECT` list. You can use `CONCAT_WS()` to combine the list of columns into a comma-separated list. It will omit `NULL` values, so this will just list the matched fields.

```
database.query(`SELECT *, 
    CONCAT_WS(',', 
        IF(username = ?, 'username', NULL), 
        IF(email = ?, 'email', NULL), 
        IF(mobile = ?, 'mobile', NULL)) AS matched_fields 
FROM accounts WHERE username = ? OR email = ? OR mobile = ?`, [username, email, mobile, username, email, mobile], (err, result) => {
  var matched = result.matched_fields.split(',');
  matched.each(field => {
    switch(field) {
    case 'username': ...; break;
    case 'email': ...; break;
    case 'mobile': ...; break;
  });
})
```

Comment: I thought of that, but it is not different from using `if()` (in my code). So to imporve it, is it possible to put all the "AS" in an array to be returned as an array so I can just iterate that? something like `AS matched[fieldname]`

Comment: I've updated it to show how to get them all into a single column. SQL doesn't have arrays, so you have to use comma-separated strings.

Answer (score 0):

Try Below:-

```
SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE (username = "aaa" OR email = "abc@example.com" OR mobile = "123456789")
```

Answer (score 0):

Create custom column in select query and that custom column has case statement with three column(username, email, mobile) matching and print respective flag in that custom column to let it know that row comes from based on which condition.

Answer (score -1):

Whichever **field has first match** then your condition become true and **it will return result**. If you want to match all the condition then you should use **AND operator**

Comment: that's not the question. He wants to know which condition caused the row to match.